# Sum of three numbers and the sum of their squares: $x^2+y^2+z^2 \geq \frac{1}{3}$ for $x+y+z=1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers

We have $x, y, z \in \mathbb R$ such that $x+y+z=1$. Prove that $x^2+y^2+z^2 \geq \frac{1}{3}$. I am able to do this using the relationship between the power and arithmetic means. Is there a way to not use this relationship?

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2247973/inequality-proof-is-there-a-simpler-way-to-solve-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $(x-\frac13)^2 + (y-\frac13)^2 + (z-\frac13)^2 \geq 0$.

Comment: You could've edited your previous answer rather than deleting it and writing a new one.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$
x+y+z=1\\
(x+y+z)^2=1\\
x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+xz+yz)=1
$$
By the rearrangement inequality, $x^2+y^2+z^2\geq xy+xz+yz$. Inserting that gives you 
$$
3(x^2+y^2+z^2)\geq1
$$

Answer (score 1):

For *any* real numbers $x,y,z$, we have

$$\begin{align}
0\le(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2&\implies2(xy+yz+zx)\le2(x^2+y^2+z^2)\\
&\implies(x+y+z)^2\le3(x^2+y^2+z^2)
\end{align}$$

So if $x+y+z=1$, then ${1\over3}\le x^2+y^2+z^2$.